# Instantiating Derived class which inherits privately or protectedly from Base

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have the following hypothetical code:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void print() {
        std::cout << "Base\n";
    }
    // assume virtual destructor
};

class Derived : private Base {
public:
    void print() {
        std::cout << "Derived\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    // Derived d{};   works fine
    Base *pd = new Derived{}; // doesn't work
    pd->print();
    // assume memory is deallocated  
}
```

At first, I thought that it would work, because constructors aren't inherited anyways. But the compiler gives the error:

> error: 'Base' is an inaccessible base of 'Derived'

And I'm not able to figure out what is really happening?

Comment: Private and protected inheritance is different from public inheritance. Why would we have three kinds of inheritance otherwise? The difference is that private and protected inheritance produce errors at places where public inheritance would work (exactly like with public/private/protected members). That's one of such places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a good guess, but the problem isn't with constructors or member functions.

In the line

> ```
> Base *pd = new Derived{}; // doesn't work
> ```

The compiler is implicitly converting the right side, `new Derived{}`, which is of type `Derived*`, to the type `Base*`.

The term that the standard uses to describe when one can implicitly convert a pointer to a derived class to a pointer to a base class is *accessibility*. From subsection 11.2/5:

> If a base class is accessible, one can implicitly convert a pointer to a derived class to a pointer to that base class

There are a few technical conditions listed (11.2/4 if you really care) that can make a base class accessible, but Base meets none of these.

The short version is, `private` inheritance hides the base class and the access specifier `private` needs to be `public` for your code to compile. Hope that helps.

Comment: "the access specifier `private` needs be `protected` or `public` for your code to compile" - I think the inheritance should be `public` for the code to compile. Protected inheritance should still be invisible to the `main` function.

Answer (score 1):

You are deriving `Base` privately, and that's why you are getting error.

With private inheritance, all members from the base class are inherited as private. This means private members stay private, and protected and public members become private. Thats why you are not able to use `print()`in `main` Compiler is not able to cast `derived` pointer to `base` type, because the inheritance is private.

Answer (score 0):

In a context where the knowledge of the internals of the derived class is hidden (IE non-friend, not in a class derived from Derived) it seems like there is no relationship between the two classes.

When you try to assign to a pointer of the base type you are saying convert this Derived pointer to a Base pointer. As the inheritance is hidden, it is like you are trying to assign it to a pointer of an unrelated type. However the compiler does know that it is related, so rather than just giving you a unhelpful error, it tells you that the conversion that you are trying to do is inaccessible.

Comment: Private inheritance [has indeed similarities with a 'has a' relationship](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/private-inheritance#priv-inherit-like-compos), but remains fundamentally an 'is-a' relationship : members can upcast to the base and the class can override virtual functions.  The main difference is that the 'is-a' relationship is kept as a private implementation detail.

Comment: @Christophe, thanks. It is more subtle than I believed.